# A question about Riemannian geometry

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be an n-dimensional Riemannian manifold, and $f: M\to S^n$ be a smooth map, $df$ be the differential of $f$. Set

$$U=\{x\in \text{supp}\ (df)| |df|<1/2\}$$

$$V=\{x| |\Lambda^2(df)|>1/2\}$$

where $\Lambda^2(df)$ is the induced map of $df$ on the exterior product $\Lambda^2(TM)$.

**I'm a little confused with the conclusion:
$$\overline{V}\cap \overline{U}=\emptyset.$$**

Why are they intersect in the case that inequality becomes equality at $1/2$?

Could you give me some help with the details? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $\Lambda^2(df)$ and, in a second step, it's norm? Asked a bit differently - why exactly does the claim confuse you? What would you expect?

Comment: I don't know it clearly.@Thomas

Comment: Then you might want to look up the definitions...

Comment: It may help to consider an Euclidean space $(V,\langle, \rangle)$ and consider those covectors $\omega \in V^*$ such that $||\omega||<1/2$  such that $||\omega \wedge \omega||>1/2$.

Comment: Clearly, $U\cap V=\emptyset$, but I'm confused with their closure interest to the empty set.  @WarlockofFiretopMountain

Comment: You’re still not paying attention to anything but the number $1/2$. Edit your question to include the definitions of the actual quantities here.